# Mysql query to select from multiple ranges

Tags: mysql

I need some help. I've tried to search for the answer without success/

I need to select records from a table by price field which value must be in one of the ranges. Let me explain

```
select * from items 
    where color = 'black'
    AND shape = 'square'
    AND price between 333 and 444
    OR price between 777 and 888
```

But this will ignore color and shape conditions. What is the correct syntax for that? Is this a correct approach at all?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`and` has a higher operator precedence than `or`. You need parentheses to manage that

```
select * from items 
where color = 'black'
AND shape = 'square'
AND 
(
   price between 333 and 444
   OR price between 777 and 888
)
```

Comment: Thanks. That was a problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think below useful to you. please check it once.

```
 select * from items 
        where color = 'black'
        AND shape = 'square'
        AND ((price between 333 and 444)
        OR (price between 777 and 888))
```